# Matrix-Vector Multiplication - Sparse vs. Dense matrices

Tags: matrix, parallel-processing

I want to implement a matrix-vector multiplication in C. My matrix is 1000 * 1000^2 and highly sparse (less than 0.01% non-zero elements). The non-zero elements are dispersed among the rows (between 0 to 126 non-zero elements per row).

I have heard that generally, using parallel processing for sparse matrix-vector multiplication is challenging and not as efficient as dense matrices because the ratio of computation to memory access is low ([Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13636464/slow-sparse-matrix-vector-product-csr-using-open-mp)). But I cannot really understand what is the main difference between a sparse and a dense matrix with respect to parallel computation that makes sparse matrices less efficient.It seems the same problem is  still around for the dense matrices (please correct me if I am wrong).

It is appreciated if let me know how dense matrices differ from sparse matrices in terms of parallel processing.
Thanks

Comment: I think the point is that you don't stand to gain much from the sparsity of your matrix. Ideally a matrix with n = 0.01% of the elements would take that much less time to multiply, but in reality (depending on what you do and how yo do it) you may well be much close to the cost of just doing a dense multiplication for a matrix of the same size. (For example if you have a more complex data structure how does the cost of the traversal compare to the cost of the memory accesses, even if you manage to reduce the total number of floating point ops needed).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Suppose, we have a new dense matrix (B) with the same number of elements of the original sparse matrix (A). (the size of the dense matrix would be much smaller). The matrix-vector multiplications A*x and B*x require almost the same number of FLOPs and the number of non-zero elements are the same in both matrices. My question is, what is the difference between A*x and B*x in terms of memory access? which one would be faster? Thanks

Comment: For the same number of non-zero elements it still depends how you're storing your sparse matrix to some extent. Probably on SIMD hardware the dense case would be faster since it just becomes a case of iterating over a single block of memory and doing the right `_mm_mul_ps` (or similar) in a tight loop as fast as they can be fed into the pipeline. In the sparse case the memory access will typically be less sequential, with more branches (bad for pipelining).

Comment: Ideally you'd take exactly the same amount of time for each if the number of non-zero elements is the same but that's hard to do even if you optimise for specific layouts of sparse matrices and even with all the optimisations you'll probably still have a few cases where there's extra work being done or work being done sub-optimally.